# SwiftUI how to prevent the .repeatforever animation being stopped by other animation

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, uikit

Here is an example, I want to make the "hello world" keep moving back and forth. While in the outer level, I want to change its offset, but when I animate the offset outside, the `.repeatforever` stops.

[image]

If I don't use offset animation outside, it won't be stopped.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var value:CGFloat = 0
    @State var bigValue:CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                    .offset(x:value)
                    .onAppear{
                        value = 10
                }
            }
            .offset(x:bigValue)
            .animation(.default, value: bigValue)
            .animation(.linear(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: false),value: value)
            Button("change"){
                bigValue = 30
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation of "Hello world" is launched by the `.onAppear` callback on the Text view. This works fine for kicking off the animation.

However, when you tap the button and set bigValue, my guess is that this causes the Text view to be built again. Since the Text view is already present, `.onAppear` is not called again, so it remains fixed in position with a final offset of 10.

To get the effect you are after, I think you need two changes:

1. Add an `.onChange` callback to react to changes of `bigValue` too
2. Reset `value` in the button callback

I think this works as you were wanting:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                    .offset(x: value)
                    .onAppear {
                        value = 10
                    }
                    // React to changes of bigValue too
                    .onChange(of: bigValue) { _ in
                        value = 10
                    }
            }
            .offset(x: bigValue)
            .animation(.default, value: bigValue)
            .animation(.linear(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: value)
            Button("change") {
                value = 0 // Reset value too
                bigValue = 30
            }
        }
    }
```